# Ember link-to ignore query params to bind class `active`

Tags: ember.js

I've a simple application which fetches records for a given period, and support paging the results:

```
// routes
this.resource('visits', function() {
  this.route('list', { path: '/:period' });
});

// 'visits' template
.menu
  link-to %a.item 'visits.list' 'today' (query-params page=1)
    | Today
  link-to %a.item 'visits.list' 'yesterday' (query-params page=1)
    | Yesterday
  link-to %a.item 'visits.list' 'week' (query-params page=1)
    | Current Week
```

I wanted every time a period is clicked, it's reset to page 1. The problem is that by doing so when I go to any other page different than 1, the current `period` in the `link-to` is no longer `active`.

e.g: `http://localhost:4200/visits/today?page=5`

I tried to solve this resetting the params, or adding defaults to the controller as described here:

- http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/
- http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/link-to-helper-to-reset-query-param-s-to-null/6276

However neither of both solutions are working for me, since I'm not exiting the controller. Is any way to make link-to to ignore an specific `query-param` and stay `active`?

**Update:**

Here's a JSBin with this issue: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mulonulefi/4/edit

Thanks!

Comment: Simulate in jsbin and give the link or improve your question somehow in detail

Comment: @Susai Thanks, I've updated the question with a JSBin example.

Answer (score 6):

You can override which route will make the `{{link-to}}` active by setting the `current-when` attribute:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to 'visits.list' 'all' (query-params page=1) current-when="visits.list"}}All{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>{{#link-to 'visits.list' 'today' (query-params page=1) current-when="visits.list"}}Today{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>
```

I updated a [version of your JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kaxafe/1/edit?html,css,js,output), and I created a [JSBin with references](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xitayo/3/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score -1):

Does page variable work properly? Try to use quotes (query-params page='1')...